# REST Controller Not found in Spring Boot 3.0.3 applications. I did not find any good solutions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I have a small toy example with spring boot 3.0.3.

[image]

These are my two simple classes:

```
package org.crea.water4agrifoodmock;

import org.crea.water4agrifoodmock.controller.ModelMockerController;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

// added this @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"org.crea.water4agrifoodmock", "org.crea.water4agrifoodmock.controller"}) but without valid result
@SpringBootApplication
public class Water4AgriFoodMockApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(
                Water4AgriFoodMockApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and the controller:

```
package org.crea.water4agrifoodmock.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(name = "/api/v1")
public class ModelMockerController {

    @GetMapping(name = "/mock")
    public String hello(){
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

The best practice is to place the Main Application class at the root of your project. This way, it will automatically scan and find the Controller class which are available in a sub-package. For example, here is a package structure that works in this [page](http://www.masterspringboot.com/web/rest-services/rest-controller-not-found-in-spring-boot-applications-how-to-solve-it/):

[image]

I got this error message in Postman:

[image]

my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.crea</groupId>
    <artifactId>water4agrifood-mock</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>water4agrifood-mock</name>
    <description>Demo project water4agrifood-mockSpring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This the run view

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.3)

2023-02-28T16:17:47.705+01:00  INFO 15268 --- [           main] o.c.w.Water4AgriFoodMockApplication      : Starting Water4AgriFoodMockApplication using Java 19.0.1 with PID 15268 (C:\Users\*****\spring-boot-water4agrifood-model-mocker\water4agrifood-mock\target\classes started by ***** in C:\Users\*****\spring-boot-water4agrifood-model-mocker\water4agrifood-mock)
2023-02-28T16:17:47.708+01:00  INFO 15268 --- [           main] o.c.w.Water4AgriFoodMockApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-02-28T16:17:48.409+01:00  INFO 15268 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-02-28T16:17:48.416+01:00  INFO 15268 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-02-28T16:17:48.416+01:00  INFO 15268 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-02-28T16:17:48.489+01:00  INFO 15268 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-02-28T16:17:48.490+01:00  INFO 15268 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 737 ms
2023-02-28T16:17:48.658+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2023-02-28T16:17:48.721+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 2 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2023-02-28T16:17:48.733+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/webjars/**, /**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2023-02-28T16:17:48.738+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [           main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2023-02-28T16:17:48.792+01:00  INFO 15268 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-02-28T16:17:48.799+01:00  INFO 15268 --- [           main] o.c.w.Water4AgriFoodMockApplication      : Started Water4AgriFoodMockApplication in 1.427 seconds (process running for 1.927)
2023-02-28T16:17:53.490+01:00  INFO 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-02-28T16:17:53.490+01:00  INFO 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-02-28T16:17:53.490+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2023-02-28T16:17:53.490+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2023-02-28T16:17:53.490+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2023-02-28T16:17:53.490+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@6deaf644
2023-02-28T16:17:53.491+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@57d613cd
2023-02-28T16:17:53.491+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2023-02-28T16:17:53.491+01:00  INFO 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-02-28T16:17:53.497+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/v1/mock", parameters={}
2023-02-28T16:17:53.508+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-02-28T16:17:53.515+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2023-02-28T16:17:53.516+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2023-02-28T16:17:53.520+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2023-02-28T16:17:53.521+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2023-02-28T16:17:53.541+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2023-02-28T16:17:53.543+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Tue Feb 28 16:17:53 CET 2023, status=404, error=Not Found, path=/api/v1/mock}]
2023-02-28T16:17:53.571+01:00 DEBUG 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

After adding `logging.level.root=DEBUG` (just some parts)

```
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1079) ~[na:na]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:637) ~[na:na]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:679) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1449) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1405) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getAttribute(RMIConnectionImpl.java:639) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:598) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:844) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:721) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:720) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]



2023-02-28T16:44:36.181+01:00 DEBUG 14952 --- [           main] _.s.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.Mappings  : 
    o.s.b.a.w.s.e.BasicErrorController:
    { [/error]}: error(HttpServletRequest)
    { [/error], produces [text/html]}: errorHtml(HttpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse)
```

Comment: please post your full debug logs from the startup of the service and a request

Comment: @Toerktumlare added the screen run view

Comment: The answer by Paul_K is correct. `name` is not the appropriate annotation element to set the path. Either use `value` or `path`, which are synonyms.

Comment: for future questions @GianniSpear i asked for full logs, not just a selected section by you. i dont want your interpretation of the logs. For instance, i wanted to see in your logs if your endpoints where registered during startup, but you decided to just post what you thought was relevant, which does not contain what i wanted to read. So when we ask for full logs, we want full logs.

Comment: After fixing the `name` vs `path` element issue, you''re likely dealing with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75573888/whitelabel-error-page-when-making-get-request

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute in both `@RequestMapping` and `@GetMapping` just configure the name of the mapping. It is nothing related to the API path. You should use `path` or `value` instead :

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class ModelMockerController {

    @GetMapping("/mock")
    public String hello(){
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

or

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1")
public class ModelMockerController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/mock")
    public String hello(){
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it indeed was the problem, because I forgot to write `path` in the `@GetMapping`, which led to a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the project with Spring version 3.0.4.

I had the same problem for 2 days, and it worked when I used Spring version 3.0.4, so I guess Spring version 3.0.3 has a bug or something.

I hope it works out for you.